# Using a non-template nested class in a template

Tags: c++, templates, nested

I am new to templates, and I have been forced to use one in a function while the underlying class used is not a template.
A very simple case where my problem occurs is the following :

```
//test.h

struct Top
{
    struct Bottom
    {
    };

    Bottom bot;
};


//test.cpp

void without_template(Top content)
{
    Top::Bottom bot = content.bot;
}

template<typename T>
void with_template(T content)
{
    // Uncomment to get an error :
    // T::Bottom bot = content.bot; 
}

template<typename T>
void with_template_2(T content)
{
    auto bot = content.bot; 
}
```

(Currently, my code works using "auto", but I would like to avoid using it like that, this looks really unsafe.)
(Also, in the actual code, everything is in .h, but the same thing occurs.)

The error is C2760 : syntax error: expected ";" after "T" ; followed by C7510 : 'Bottom' : a dependent type name has to be preceeded by 'type name'
(sorry for not quoting it exactly, my compiler is in French)

I though templates were basically just inlining the type name, but apparently not. So what is going on here ? In particular, there is an error even if "with_template" is never called...

My best guess is that the syntax "T::..." is simply not supported, but I don't see why that would be the case.

Is there an elegant fix ? (appart from making the underlying class a template, which would just propagate the use of templates in my code)

(I also tried "using namespace", but it doesn't seem to work.)

Comment: Your question has an excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/2144408). In your specific case, it boils down to: Go to the line of the error; add a specific typename for the variable, referring to 'T::Bottom' with 'typename ' at the start. For example; 'using B = typename T::Bottom'. This is to indicate that Bottom is a typename within T, not a static constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a template function, the template parameters are unknown when the compiler parses it. That means that anything that depends on a template parameter is basically also unknown. Because the compiler can't know what `Bottom` is, you need to tell it what to expect.

If you don't tell it anything the compiler will assume it's a member or member function, this it will figure out by itself from context. But if it's a type, you need to explicitly say so.

```
template<typename T>
void with_template(T content)
{
    typename T::Bottom bot = content.bot;
     // ^-- typename here tells the compiler that Bottom is a type
}
```

More information on [dependent names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).